# What is the parameter 'i' in the method handleClick() is being used for?

Tags: reactjs

What is the parameter `i` in the method `handleClick()` is being used for?

Why aren't we passing `i` when `this.props.onClick()` in the `Square` is being called?

Is `i` an event object?

```
class Square extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <button 
        className="square" 
        onClick={()=> this.props.onClick()}
        >
          {this.props.value}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
        };
    }

    handleClick(i){
        const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        squares[i] = 'X';
        this.setState({squares: squares});
    }

    renderSquare(i) {
      return (
      <Square 
      value={this.state.squares[i]}
      onClick = {()=> this.handleClick(i)}
      
      />);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i` in handleClick refers to the index of the Square in the `this.state.squares` array in the board. If you look at the renderSquare function of Board, it returns a Square with the prop onClick set to `()=> this.handleClick(i)`, which means that when a square is clicked, it calls this.handleClick and gives it `i` to tell it which square was clicked.